# NextJS Global Server-Side Variables to Share Data Between API Calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm somewhat new to typescript in NextJS and still learning some of the ins and outs of the framework.

I was following a tutorial in JS and have been converting it to TS. Perhaps this could be to be blame? Not too sure.

My folder structure is quite simple. I just have added a /utils folder in the root of my project:

/pages

/public

/styles

/utils

The problem is that in the tutorial, a global key-value store is created/exported in /utils
as follows:

```
/* utils/users.js */
export const users = {}
```

I converted it to TS as follows:

```
/* utils/users.ts */
type user_i = {
        address: string,
        nonce: Number
}

export const users : {
    [key:string] : user_i,
}={}
```

But as I call 2 unique api calls from /pages/api/auth.ts then /pages/api/verify.ts, the first stores a new value in users global object, then second reads it.

```
/* /pages/api/auth.ts */
export default function auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  ...

  ...
  console.log(users);
}
```

At the end of auth.ts, I run `console.log(users)` and I can see the 1 value is loaded into the 'users' variable. Then at the beginning of verify.ts, I run console.log(users) and it shows as empty.

```
/* /pages/api/verify.ts */
export default function verify(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  console.log("useres: " + JSON.stringify(users));
  ...
}
```

So my question is, how can I share the object between the api calls without creating an entire DB for a single variable. From the tutorial, it seems like it works in js but maybe my ts conversion is causing problems.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks